# Catel Mapping properties to Model

Tags: c#, wpf, catel

I have problem with AutoMapping Catel ViewModel -> Model properties.

I'm using Catel with Fody.Catel

I have a situation when my model changes during runtime.

My Model declaration looks like this:

```
[Model]
public MyModel SelectedMyModel { get; set; }
```

And I change this model during runtime like this:

```
private void TabChangedHandler(TabChangedMessage tabChangedMessage)
{
    SelectedMyModel = (MyModel) tabChangedMessage.Data;
}
```

Then, I'm delegating some properties from Model to ViewModel like this:

```
[ViewModelToModel("SelectedMyModel")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[ViewModelToModel("SelectedMyModel")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

And the problem is:

When I'm setting this property for the first time, it works nice, but If I change SelectedMyModel to another object, it stops working.

Looks like delegation ViewModel -> Model is no longer working.

Should I call something to let Catel know, that my Model is changing? Or maybe it's a Catel issue?

Can you please help me?

Comment: It should all work out of the box. If you think you found a bug, please report it at http://catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker